# Python list addition and equating variables

Tags: python, list, variables

I have the following code

```
def do_something(a,b):
    a.insert(0, 'z')
    b = ['z'] + b

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a1 = a
a2 = a[:]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b1 = b
b2 = [:]
do_something(a,b)
```

After this is executed, these are what all the variables refer to:

```
a = ['z','a','b','c']
a1 = ['z','a','b','c']
a2 = ['a','b','c']
b = ['a','b','c']
b1 = ['a','b','c']
b2 = ['a','b','c']
```

My questions are:
why did a1 change to include 'z' but a2 did not?
why did b, b1 and b2 not change at all even though b = ['z'] + b was executed?
Thank you

Comment: because b is a local variable inside that function, you would need to return it. a1 has same id as a but a2 doesn't

Comment: The first line modifies `a` in place. The second line creates, returns, and assigns a new object from `b`. Variable != object.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ohhhh I understand now! So The b variable inside the function is different completely from the b variable that was declared outside it right? They are stored in different places in memory right?

Comment: Yes, and yes....

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ understood! thanks a lot!

Comment: @SpaSmALX it is not helpful to think about *memory locations of the variables*, rather, instead think about the *object identity* of the objects the variables are referring to. `a` is similarly a *different variable* than the `a` outside the function, however, when the funciton starts executing, `a` and `b` *both refer to the same objects as the `a` and `b` variables outside*, but that is due to how you named your parameters and the values you passed. You *mutate* the object referred to by `a`, so that change is visible in the caller. With `b`, you simply create and reassign the local variable

Comment: @SpaSmALX read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html Note, Python variables are not like variables in C, they are not references to particular locations in memory, rather, they are more like name-tags that you can place on *any object*. The objects themselves have a unique location in memory, variables do not (well, not in an introspectable way...)

Answer (score 0):

This explains the a2 question:

```
def do_something(a,b):
    a.insert(0, 'z')
    print(id(b))
    b = ['z'] + b
    print(id(b))

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']; a1 = a; a2 = a[:]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']; b1 = b; b2 = b[:]

do_something(a,b)

for var in (a,a1,a2,b,b1,b2):
    print(id(var), end=" ")
    print(var)
```

Prints

```
4639127112                      # this is the id of b before new assign
4639513416                      # this is the id of b inside the function after
4639486216 ['z', 'a', 'b', 'c'] # a    (same as a1)
4639486216 ['z', 'a', 'b', 'c'] # a1
4639511944 ['a', 'b', 'c']      # a2
4639127112 ['a', 'b', 'c']      # b    (same as b1)
4639127112 ['a', 'b', 'c']      # b1
4639487304 ['a', 'b', 'c']      # b2
```

Comment: Ohh so their ID stays the same, meaning they are stored in the same place in memory? That's why they both change?

Comment: @SpaSmALX look again. When you reassign b the id is lost

Comment: Glad it helped you understand more :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to explain this is just comment the code:

```
def do_something(a,b):
    a.insert(0, 'z')      #insert a 'z' at the start of a that has been passed into the function (modify it)
    b = ['z'] + b         #assign a local variable (b) to a list containing [z] concatenated with b

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']  #define normal list
a1 = a               #set a1 to refer to a (from now on they will always have the same contents
a2 = a[:]            #make a copy of a so this can have different contents to a
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']  #define normal list
b1 = b               #set b1 to refer to b
b2 = [:]             #make a copy of b
```

So, none of the `b*` variables will ever change as when the function is called, it modifies the **`local`** variable `b`.

As for the `a` variables, the function does modify `a` and since `a1` points to `a`, it thus also modifies `a1` as well. As for `a2`, this was created as a copy of the original `a` list *before* the function call, so remains with the same `['a', 'b', 'c']` contents.